# Подключение OpenCV к проекту Java

Tags: java, opencv, path, javacv

При выполнении кода из [туториала](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/d52/tutorial_java_dev_intro.html):

```
static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
        Mat m = new Mat(5, 10, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
        System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + m);
        Mat mr1 = m.row(1);
        mr1.setTo(new Scalar(1));
        Mat mc5 = m.col(5);
        mc5.setTo(new Scalar(5));
        System.out.println("OpenCV Mat data:\n" + m.dump());
    }
```

При запуске данного кода получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java410 in java.library.path:
```

Кроме всего прочего, установил OpenCV последней версии для Windovs, в системной переменной среды Path прописал путь к этой папке по мануалу одной из статей на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/190104/):

```
C:\Java_Projects\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin
```

Пролистал ответы([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644735/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-opencv-java249-in), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path/12982475)) на данную ошибку, но решения не нашел.

**Вопроса два:**

1) Почему он пытается найти версию файла 410, если у меня стоит openCV, в котором версия данного файла 411. (Может быть из-за зависимости в pom, но там прописана самая свежая)

2) Необходимо ли в переменой PAth (или где в другом месте) прописывать путь до файла с версией 411, т.к. он лежит в папке: `C:\Java_Projects\opencv\build\java\x64`
?

P.S. На второй вопрос понимаю, что необходимо, но хочу услышать правильный ответ на вопрос, где.

*pom.xml:*

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
  <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPD:**

```
Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME
```

Возвращает как раз *opencv_java410*, но тогда не совсем ясно, что делать. Загружать системную библиотеку по имени *411, или же ставить OpenCV более старой версии, в которой есть 410 версия?

Answer (score 0):

Решение, которое сработало, но я не до конца уверен, что оно верное, это в параметрах запуска прописать путь до 411 библиотеки:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Java_Projects\opencv\build\java\x64"
```

В этой папке переименовать 411 библиотеку в 410, которую ищет. 
Тогда код запускается и работает, но я не думаю - что это верный вариант. Хотелось бы узнать правильный ответ.